# What are some mathematically productive ways to waste time?

Tags: soft-question, big-list

What are some productive things that can be done (other than directly studying Mathematics) during leisure time that has a side effect to improve oneself at Mathematics? For example, reading Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Inspired by [What to do while compiling?](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/970/what-to-do-while-compiling)

Comment: browsing stackexchange ;)

Comment: @Denis: Better yet, solving problems therein.

Comment: [Sleep thinking](http://www.amazon.com/Sleep-Thinking-Revolutionary-Problems-Creativity/dp/1580624456).

Comment: Drinking, of course.

Comment: Can we please try to give more than one-line answers to this question?

Comment: @Emrakul: That's a mathematical way to waste time too. Give one-line answers to this question.

Answer (score 8):

> [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/): is a series of challenging mathematical/computer programming problems that will require more than just mathematical insights to solve. Although mathematics will help you arrive at elegant and efficient methods, the use of a computer and programming skills will be required to solve most problems.

Solving Project Euler problems is an interesting and addicting pastime.

---

[This Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13638/which-popular-games-are-the-most-mathematical) question has a good collection of games that are both popular and mathematical. Some examples are [set](https://mathoverflow.net/a/13645), [hex](https://mathoverflow.net/a/13652) and [lights out](https://mathoverflow.net/a/13712).

---

[Math puzzles for dinner](https://mathoverflow.net/q/29323) is another Mathoverflow post which has lot of interesting answers.

Answer (score 4):

How about inventing games with dice or coins, and then analyzing them?

Answer (score 3):

Learn a little coding (for example python) and practise with old problems from the google coding championships.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do putnam competition tests. You don't really learn a lot of theory but it's a good exercise in coming up with proofs.

Answer (score 2):

Carry a book about an area of maths, and read bits of it?
Do smallish mathematical puzzles?
Practice mental arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

Assembling a 100+ piece jigsaw puzzle. This will improve your ability to visualize shapes.

Answer (score 0):

How about calculating the value of 2^52 without a calculator

Comment: In middle school I did this to $2^{100}$.

Comment: without calculator?

Comment: @Meelo I just did it without calculator, With Mathematica :P

Comment: @Integrator These days, I'd be smart enough to just do it in base $2$ - and I wouldn't need no fancy computation for that!

Comment: 2^52 tries for SHA-1 encryption info http://eurocrypt2009rump.cr.yp.to/837a0a8086fa6ca714249409ddfae43d.pdf

Comment: According to various sources, attacks looking for sha-1 collisions have been improved to 2^52 operations:

http://www.secureworks.com/research/blog/index.php/2009/6/3/sha-1-collision-attacks-now-252/